# Facebook Registration Plugin and Name Field

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I am trying to use FaceBook Registration Plugin (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/). It already has name field which I dont want to use instead i want to use my own First Name and Last Name fields Is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this this using view field.